# Passing a variable to a bash script results in the variable disappearing in the script it was sent to?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've been trying to create a script so I can launch things as background processes. The usual ways of &, disown, etc I see on Google all result in either the current terminal having the output of the background process I've launched, requiring me to perform extra actions in the current terminal, being unable to close the terminal, etc.

So I wanted to write a simple command called bgp to launch a background process. To do this I launch a new terminal instance, then from that I launch a script that runs the process and then immediately exits the second terminal instance. The first bgp.sh script is:

```
bash -c 'gnome-terminal -x nohup bash ~/scripts/bgp_exec.sh $1 &'
```

Then the second bgp_exec.sh is:

```
nohup '$1' & exit
```

I've split it up into two files as I couldn't find a way to use quotation marks to correctly format it all on one line.

The problem is that while $1 in the first script is e.g. bconf-editor, in the second script it's nothing. What's weirder is if I change the first script to:

```
bash -c 'gnome-terminal -x nohup bash ~/scripts/bgp_exec.sh bconf-editor &'
```

Then in the second script $1 is correctly bconf-editor.

Why is this happening? In the mean time to solve it I've just done:

```
rm bgp_exec.sh
echo "nohup '$1' & exit" >> bgp_exec.sh
bash -c 'gnome-terminal -x nohup bash ~/scripts/bgp_exec.sh $1 &'
```

Comment: Try this function: `bgp() { nohup "$@" < /dev/null &> /dev/null & disown; }`. And anyway, `'$1'` is exactly the characters `$` and `1`; you probably wanted `"$1"`. But try the function first.

Comment: Thanks AlexP, that works. But the '$1' isn't the issue, in fact that works just fine if I send it something else, it's just that the variable is disappearing in the second script for some reason.

Although I've got the solution I'd still like to know what's happening here.

Comment: **How** are you passing the variable to the second script? Is `$1` really single-quoted in `bgp_exec.sh`?

Comment: steeldriver exactly the way I'm doing it in my post. If I remove the quotes it doesn't change anything.